# incrementally un-hide input boxes and text with 1 button

Tags: jquery

I have a couple input boxes that are generated dynamically and are attached on the bottom of some lists. These are for custom user input, alongside selected objects. I need this to be expandable by 1 upon each push of a button. I'm really new with jquery so I'm sure I've mixed up the syntax somewhere but I'm not really sure where. When I click my button nothing happens. What am I missing?

Here's my jquery:

```
var addanother;
function increment(){
    addanother++;
    $('input['.addmore'="'+ addanother +'"]').show();   
}
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<input type="button" onClick="increment()" value="Add more!"/>
<div>
<div class="addmore1" style="display: none" />
<input id="<?php echo $catkey; ?>_addone_friendly_1" type="text" class="auto" size="9" /><span> - Friendly</span><br />
<input id="<?php echo $catkey; ?>_addone_1" name="[<?php echo $catkey; ?>][]" type="text" class="auto" size="9" /><span> - Exact</span><br />
</div>
<div class="addmore2" style="display: none" />
<input id="<?php echo $catkey; ?>_addone_friendly_2" type="text" class="auto" size="9" /><span> - Friendly</span><br /><br />
<input id="<?php echo $catkey; ?>_addone_2" name="[<?php echo $catkey; ?>][]" type="text" class="auto" size="9" /><span> - Exact</span><br /><br />
</div>
... and so on
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks but adeneo nailed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To increment something, it has to start with something other than `undefined`, and you mixed the quotes:

```
var addanother = 0;

function increment(){
    addanother++;
    $('.addmore'+addanother).show();   
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tLgRD/)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to approach this would be to get rid of the sequence numbers, just make all of them `class="addmore"`, and let jquery find the first one that's hidden and show it.

```
function increment() {
  $('.addmore').filter(':hidden').eq(0).show()
}
```